# Curvature of the Archimedean spiral in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry

Let's take a look on the Archimedean spiral. The parametric equation  is:

$$c : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{2} \,;\, c(t) := (t\cos(t), t\sin(t))$$

The goal of the exercise is to compute the curvature of the spiral in polar coordinates.  What I've tried? I convert the parametric equation into polar coordinates:

$$x(\varphi) = r(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)$$

$$y(\varphi) = r(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)$$ Is that correct so far?

I know how to compute the curvature with the parametric equation, that's not the point. But how I can do it with the polar coordinates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know how to calculate the derivative of the polar coordinates. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Did you find what is $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$?

Comment: Search "polar" in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). Can it help ?

Comment: @John: $r(t)$ is the radius, $\theta(t)$ is the angle in dependence of the parameter t, right? How I can find it?

Comment: @cvis: $r(t)$ is the radius, also the length $|c(t)|$, while $\theta(t)$ is the angle made by $c(t)$ and the $x$-axis. You can check that it is just given by the answer by Ross Millikan below.

Comment: @John: Ross Millikan replied that $r=t$ and $\theta =t$. His $\theta$ is the $\varphi$ in the formula that Michael Hoppe posted, right? Now I have just to apply the formula, it look very simple so far?

Comment: I guess so, do you have the formula for curvature in polar coordinate?

Comment: @John: Is the formula correct that Michael Hoppe posted below? I have no other one..

Comment: @cvis: You can use the simpler formula that I found on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature . It seems that the formula posted by Michael Hoppe is correct though.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r$, $\varphi\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be $C^{\infty}$.
Applying the definition of the curvature to $\gamma=r\cdot(\cos\mathrel\circ\varphi,\sin\mathrel\circ\varphi)$,
a lengthy calculation shows that
$$\kappa=\frac{r^2\dot\varphi^3+2\dot r^2\dot\varphi-r\ddot r\dot\varphi+r\dot r\ddot\varphi}{(\dot r^2+r^2\dot\varphi^2)^{3/2}}$$

In your case: $r(t)=\varphi(t)=t$, hence $\kappa(t)=\frac{t^2+2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}^3}$.

Comment: How I can find the $r$ and $\varphi$ in the formula? Can I just follow Ross Millikan's post and say  $r=t, \varphi=t$. Is that all?

Comment: Every time when it looks very simple I'm cunfused a little bit

Comment: @cvis  I've enhanced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your parametric equation in polar is $r=t, \theta=t$

Comment: That is right. And there is not such a "lengthy calculation" using the equation posted by Michael Hoppe.  It is immediate after this parametrization.  The question is why, when $t \to 0$ the curvature is not infinity. Isn't the spiral supposed to collapse to a point (which as infinite curvature? )

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$r=θ \\
dr/dθ=1 \\
ds=ρdθ \\
(rdθ)2+(dr)2=(ds)2 \\
(rdθ)2+(dr)2=(ρdθ)2 \\
(r)2+(dr/dθ)2=(ρ)2 \\
(r)2+(1)2=(ρ)2 \\
ρ=\sqrt{r2+1}=\sqrt{θ2+1}$$

Comment: Can you add some further detail or comment? Is $\theta$ the angle $\varphi$ mentioned in the question?

Comment: the explicit form of the curve is r=teta and the figure shown is at a point wit r and teta and an adjacent point with r+dr and teta+d(teta) distanced away by ds.